# Moodle Upgrade: Uncaught Error: Class 'cache' not found

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to upgrade a moodle from version **3.10.8** to version **4.2.1**
After several attempts, following the official documentation, I always get the same error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'cache' not found

I done "*purge all cache*" from moodle panel and ran the "*cron*" file but I still get the same error

Anyone know how to fix?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Enable debugging in `config.php` so it displays a trace, then copy and paste the error message into the question above

```
// Force a debugging mode regardless the settings in the site administration
@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
@ini_set('display_errors', '1');    // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // === DEBUG_DEVELOPER - NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;             // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
```

Also check the data directory is writeable

```
$CFG->dataroot  = '/home/example/moodledata';
```

You can also *usually* delete the cache folder in the dataroot, Moodle will re-create it - backup everything before you do though, just in case